# SMTP Login attemp detection

Tags: smtp, login-control, smtp-auth, protect-from-forgery

Is there a way to detect SMTP logins particularly those that do not succeed in the first attempt? When email client is configured with the save-password option; there is too little chance that smtp access will fail. Hence, if smtp login access fails, I believe, it should be an invalid/forgery attempt.

How can I know if a user is trying to login into the SMTP?

Comment: I don't know what the "save password option" is, but fail2ban for one comes with script for SMTP servers - http://www.fail2ban.org. There are similar tools to fail2ban available. Hope that helps.

Comment: save password option: Your email client can be configured to store the SMTP password and login details while checking for emails or sending them. So, there is no chance of sending wrong password. I want to detect the failing SMTP login attempts that may be a forgery attempt.

Comment: Oh right, client side. fail2ban approach holds if your server is Linux. Not sure what exists for MS.

Comment: Your SMTP server should log unsuccessful authentication attempts.  You ought to be able to find the unsuccessful attempts by parsing your logs.